# Laravel не видит локально подключенные js файлы, а видит только cdn

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, slick.js, cdn

Всем привет. Я вообще не очень люблю подключать к сайтам что то извне, но в случае с laravel иного решения не нашел.
К примеру я хочу подключить `jquery`. С офф сайта скачал `jquery-3.5.1.min.js`, закинул в папку `resourses/js`.
В webpack mix прописал его `.js('resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', 'public/js')`(кстати, обязательно ли добавлять в `webpack` файлы готовых `js` скриптов?) и теперь в нужном мне шаблоне подключаю  и почему то laravel его не видит. Если же подключу через `cdn` , то уже все работает. Не пойму где я допускаю ошибку. Вроде версии что локального файла, что удаленного одинаковые.
P.S.Та же ерунда и со `slick slider`, подключается только удаленный `js` файл,а вот `jquery.fancybox.min.js` и `bootstrap.min.js` подключенные локально, работают без проблем.
Структура сайта выглядит примерно так.Есть общий файл, через @yield подключаю нужные js и css скрипты.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/fa-svg/laptop-house-solid.svg" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/general.css">
  @yield('pagescss')

<title>@yield('tittle')</title>
</head>
<body>
  @include('inc.header')

  @yield('content')

  @include('inc.footer')

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/534eca2594.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  @yield('pagesjs')
<script src="/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Так выглядит пример страницы:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('pagescss')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/product.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/slick-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
@endsection

@section('tittle', 'Товары')

@section('content')
Тут много контента.
@endsection
@section('pagesjs')
<script src="/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
@endsection
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если кладете скрипты/стили в `resourses`, то надо кроме добавления записи в webpack mix ещё запускать [команду](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#running-mix), чтобы эти файлы обработались и результат обработки сохранился в папке `public`. Если у вас есть готовый скрипт и вы не собираетесь его собирать, минимизивать, перенастраивать и т.д. то можно его сразу положить в `public`.

Comment: Прикол какой то. Вот решил по вашему совету уже готовые скрипты из `webpack'a` убрать и все сразу в `public` закинуть и заработало)Очень навязчивое чувство,что я уже так делал,видать где то не доделал).
Спасибо за помощь!)